# Edit / remove navigation bar in asp.net app

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an easy way to edit or remove the navigation bar at the top of ASP.NET applications that use Twitter Bootstrap?

[image]

The "Register" and "Log in" links need to be removed and the "Application Name" needs to be updated but I'm not quite sure where, in Visual Studio, I can update that info. CSS file?

It's a one page web app so technically it doesn't even need the navigation bar at the top so if there is a way to remove it -- and that's easier than editing it -- then could you explain how to do that?

Not sure what the recommended course of action is in terms of editing and keeping it versus just removing it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should comment/remove or edit this block in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey -- this was one of those questions where once you answered it I was like "duh"; however, really appreciate you taking the time to help :-)